# many_to_many, checkboxes and cast_assoc

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I am curious what is the preferred way to get the result of a form with checkboxes representing a many_to_many relationship to save the relationship in a changeset?

Here is an example:
schema:

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :active, :boolean, default: true
    has_many :products, TestExAdmin.Product
    has_many :noids, TestExAdmin.Noid
    many_to_many :roles, TestExAdmin.Role, join_through: TestExAdmin.UserRole
  end
```

checkboxes:

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="user_roles">Roles</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="user[roles][]" type="hidden" value="">
          <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="user[roles][1]">role1</label></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

changeset:

```
  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> cast_assoc(:noids, required: false)
    |> cast_assoc(:products, required: false)
    |> cast_assoc(:roles, required: false)
  end
```

params received:

```
%{email: "test@example.com", name: "Cory",
  products: %{"1481120458618": %{_destroy: "0", price: "13.00",
      title: "A product title"}}, roles: %{"1": "on"}}
```

I currently get an error:

```
errors: [roles: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}]
```

I found this plugin, https://github.com/adam12/phoenix_mtm,  which helps solve the issue but I am wondering if there is an idiomatic solution.

Thanks,
Cory

Comment: "I currently get an error" what error?

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert I just edited it to add it, %{email: "test@example.com", name: "Cory",
  products: %{"1481122377646": %{_destroy: "0", price: "13.00",
      title: "A product title"}}, roles: %{"1": "on"}}
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{email: "test@example.com", name: "Cory",
   products: [#Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert,
     changes: %{price: #Decimal<13.00>, title: "A product title"}, errors: [],
     data: #TestExAdmin.Product<>, valid?: true>]},
 errors: [roles: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}]}],
 data: #TestExAdmin.User<>, valid?: false>

Comment: Asking in the elixir ecto google group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-ecto/s4heBrGN9J0/jwBFx3GBBAAJ

Answer (score 0):

To the error: [roles: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}],for example:

a list has many items, like:

```
schema "lists" do

    field :name, :string

    field :length, :integer

    has_many :items, AnotherAgent.Item, on_delete: :delete_all

def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :length])
    |> cast_assoc(:items, required: true)
    |> validate_required([:name, :length])
end
```

Same to your code in Template, then update or create, the list_params, like:

```
%{"items" => %{"0" => %{"body" => "ten_list_item_0", "id" => "13"} }, "length" => "10", "name" => "ten"}
```

I think the field in the "sub_schema" will need pass like this:

```
  %{"index_str" => %{"field_one" => "value1", "field_two" => "value2"}}
```